# Prove or disprove "one simple connected graph $G_n$ has no vertex of degree more than two if and only if it is $C_n$ or $C_n$ with one edge removed"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, graph-connectivity

Recently, when I self-learnt Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen, I did only the even-numbered exercises which the author offers the detailed description instead of the odd ones because the odd ones and the corresponding even ones are very similar.

I has some questions about exercise 10-supplementary-32. The problem is

> How many nonisomorphic simple connected graphs with five vertices are there
>
> a) with no vertex of degree more than two?

The answer says:

> If no degree is greater than 2 , then the graph must consist either of the 5-cycle or a walk with no vertices repeated. Therefore there are just two graphs.

Since for the path, it must have degree 2 for interior vertices and degree 1 for end vertices ("if" part proof).
Based on the above, maybe we have the following generalized statement for all numbers of vertices $n\ge 3$ "one simple connected graph has no vertex of degree more than two **if and only if** it is the cycle $C_n$ or $C_n$ with one edge removed" (Here I dropped $n=2$ because the cycle $C_2$ will cause one multigraph.)

The "if" part is already proved.

For "only if" part, I tried induction (The following uses $n$ as the number of vertices and $G_n$ the corresponding graph).

- Basis step $n=3$: This can be checked by enumeration because only 2 connected graph with $3$ vertices.
- Induction step:

  If $n=k$ holds, then for $n=k+1$. Since graphs is connected, we remove one arbitrary vertex $v$ with degree $m\le 2$ and incident edges and get $H_k=G_{k+1}-\{v\}$.

  Since $H_k$ is still connected, by *hypothesis* it is one cycle with one edge removed $C_k-\{vw\}$ or $C_{k}$.
  If $C_k$, then adding one edge it must have one vertex with degree greater than 2.
  If $C_k-\{vw\}$, then we can add one edge or 2 edges to the vertices of degree 1 (degree 0 is impossible because the graph is connected). Both cases imply $C_n$ or $C_n$ with one edge removed.

Q:

Is the "only if" part right? If right, is the above proof right?

**Edited**:

Hinted by the comments by Jfischer, I checked how to ensure preserving the subgraph's connectivity after removing one vertex. This [QA answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2461225/1059606) is helpful.

For the induction step, since $G_n$ must be one finite graph, we should remove $v$ which is the vertex corresponding to one of the endpoints of the **diameter** of $G_n$ (If $G_n$ is $C_n$ or $C_n$ with one edge removed, this vertex is the end vertex of $G_n$.) and then the "maximal" property ensures $H_k$ to be **connected**.

Trivially, $H_k$ has all vertices with degree $\le 2$. Based on this and the above proof of the connectivity property, we can use the hypothesis.

Comment: I do not understand the statement. Do you mean "a Graph with every vertex degree at most 2 is connected if and only if it is a walk connecting all vertices"?

Comment: @Jfischer Sorry for the ambiguity. I mean "For one simple connected graph $G$, $G$ has no vertex of degree more than two if and only if it is one walk connecting all vertices". So the "connected" is the assumption and "no vertex of degree more than two" is what to prove. If this solves with the ambiguity, I will update my question later.

Comment: 2. Maybe my title has grammar errors, I will update it and the corresponding question text.

Comment: You cannot assume that $H_k$ is connected, since you remove a vertex and your induction hypothesis does not include this property but can only be applied to such graphs. Also you are talking about walks and cycles interchangably but they are two very different things.

Comment: @Jfischer 1. Thanks. You are right. My hypothesis is wrong. I corrected it after your hints. Could you help verifying it? 2. I will update my question to be more specific without ambiguity of the walk and the cycle. Thanks for the clarification.